# Выбрать документы из коллекции MongoDb по параметрам

Tags: mongodb

есть коллекция из документов следующего вида:

```
{
    "_id": "6120d375524ac5a0d7a9433c",
    "name": "Mi Band 6",
    "describe": "Smart watch",
    "params": [
        {"key1": value1},
        {"key2": value2},
        ...
    ]
}
```

Задача выбрать все документы, с соответствующими параметрами (например если в документе определено 3 параметра, а при поиске заданы два, но такие же как в этом документе, то документ включается в выборку).

Comment: Найти документы у которых имеется "key1", "key2" или значения "key1", "key2" равны "value1", "value2"?

Comment: "key1", "key2" равны "value1", "value2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несправедливость судьбы - после того как написал вопрос, решение находится само.
То что мне нужно было достигается с помощью оператора `$all` - проверки на вхождение подмножества элементов. Как я это использую:

```
db.products.find({params:{$all:[{key1: value1}, {key2: value2}]}})
```

Так находятся все документы у которых массив поля param содержит `{key1:value1},{key2:value2}`